# copy Select cells with column headers to clipboard in devexpress xtragrid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

am using **devexpress** 16.1,
     in my grid i want to copy selected cells with depending columns header.
in my grid options i enabled,

```
GridView1.OptionsClipboard.AllowCopy = DefaultBoolean.True
GridView1.OptionsClipboard.CopyColumnHeaders = DefaultBoolean.True
```

but its don't copy column header with selected cells.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use `Clipboard.SetText("your contents here);` to copy into clipboard

Comment: Content only need, that my question here, while selecting multiple cells its copy to clip, but i need cell values with corresponding column header values

Comment: What happens if you invoke the GridView's CopyToClipboard method? https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView.CopyToClipboard.method

Comment: @Brendon , its copy only cells values not with responding column

Comment: Where do you paste the copied text/headers to?

Comment: like notepad file, i will paste what am copied from devexpress grid

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the CopyToClipboard() method must be used.

This copied code works to me on v15.1.7

```
    ((GridView)FocusedView).OptionsBehavior.CopyToClipboardWithColumnHeaders = true;
    FocusedView.CopyToClipboard();
```